# This site's comment scope is more permissive than the network default

Tags: discussion, comments

Although [the help page](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) sets out a fairly narrow scope for comments, law.stackexchange.com practices a more permissive scope for comments than the [text](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) sets out.

On law.stackexchange.com, if people are having fun in comments, or if the comments make a moderator smile, comments will be permitted to stay until the comment thread reaches length 20, even if a comment does not request clarification, leave constructive criticism, or add any relevant information, and even if the comment constitutes secondary discussion.

This approach intentionally ***diverges*** from the previous discussion here: [How to deal with comments?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/900/how-to-deal-with-comments) (September 26, 2019)

This approach ***is consistent with*** the moderator answer and associated comments here: [Comments that are conversational](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/comments-that-are-conversational) (November 23, 2022).

Comment: What is the goal of the question? A revised policy, solving a specific problem or something else?

Comment: To announce transparently and explicitly this site's permitted scope of comments. The practice is already in action.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree that the title and statements in the post ("question") here articulate the site's *policy*.  Rather, they reasonably describe the current *practice*.  (And reasons for the practice appear in earlier referenced threads.)

**The *policy* is still here:
https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment**

At any point any moderator or community manager could decide to enforce that policy more aggressively.

(FYI, the magic *20*-comment number is a consequence of an automated flag the system applies to comment threads that reach that length, which forces moderators to take a look at what's going on.  If that system parameter were changed then moderator attention would follow.)

Comment: I agree then, this isn't policy, just practice. I removed the "policy" tag. But whatever the label, it is important for the community to know that more comments are being permitted than https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment would suggest. Knowing that will change our flagging behaviour and invite us to be more casually chatty in comment threads.

Comment: @Jen I agree, I think this is helpful.

Comment: If this is not site policy, but is the general practice, and it's not causing problems, should we *make* it policy?

Comment: That's a different question and why I asked on the op

Comment: @Someone: Meh, comments aren't very important and I trust the moderators to use common sense. I prefer to give them the freedom to remove threads that are (in their judgment) causing a problem, rather than setting out a strict policy and having to repeatedly argue over the fringes of that policy.